# Powershell Loop Script. The process is taking too long. Can't we speed up the processing?

Tags: powershell

Below is my original question and I have already received answers but due to account suspension problem, I'm edditing the words.

https://github.com/oklokl/advfirewall-ip-list-firehol_level1.netset/blob/main/temp/out_1.csv
https://github.com/oklokl/advfirewall-ip-list-firehol_level1.netset/blob/main/temp/out_2.csv

https://github.com/oklokl/advfirewall-ip-list-firehol_level1.netset/blob/main/out.csv (final boss)

`out.csv` is the problematic one. I call it the last boss of a game.

`csv` file(or `txt` file) is consisted of pretty simple structures.

IP's are aligned and each file contains 1,000 lines.

My plan is to run these files with  `cmd` process simultaneously, like multitasking, to enhance the progression speed; which I heard is called 'multi thread' process.

Here come my real questions : How do I 'multi thread' files and how should I create the batch file? I'd like to know any efficient ways.

1.ps1

```
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Argumentlist "-file test1.ps1"
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Argumentlist "-file test2.ps1"
```

.

test1.ps1

```
$ports=get-content out_1.csv
Foreach($port in $ports){
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'A HTTP-Inbound' -Profile any -Direction Inbound -Action Block -RemoteAddress $port | Out-Null
}
exit
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDzUD.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI0jB.png]
I have tried multiple ways but none seemed to work properly.

The CPU rose up to 45% but it became so slow that it felt like as if the Windows was controling the overall speed. Are there any recommended solutions?

Below is the message I got for my failure
Below is the method I tried
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tuZC.png]

Finally, thank you everyone who answered to my questions.

I have been suspended for 6months for my previous article where I used 'translator english'.

Google translator seems to have misinterpreted my intentions which led to miscommunications and I am sorry for everything.

Nonetheless, my questions were all answered thanks to everyone here and I am trying to rectify my former mistake by asking someone to translate my actual words.

Thank you

I edited them one by one.

Comment: I open powershell in windows admin privileges. And type `.\1.ps1` to run it like this. `1.ps1` is standalone, but I want to multitask by running multiple windows.

Comment: In other words, if I run `1.ps1` in the terminal, the rest of `test1.ps1` and `test2.ps1` are executed.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Parallel execution and I want to do it in a separate process. Because it is a long operation, multi-run is required.

Comment: And I want to close the window when the multi-run is completed successfully. Leave the first window as it is. I have to write

Comment: Just input `New-Net FirewallRule` and it will work without any problem. And when it's done... it's over. And I want to leave because the window doesn't close. I don't know programming, so I'm just learning for the first time.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's because it's taking a long time. I was mistaken. I think I need to ask another question. In a new. Thank you so much. It works fine.

Comment: I think I should correct my question rather than renew it. I'll fix it.

Comment: No, don't delete it. Thanks I found the answer. Thank you very much. haha

Comment: Your script is already executing the underlying scripts in parallel so i dont think you will get much more performance from the script unfortunately :( if you are using PowerShell 7/Core then you can take a look into the [`-parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3#example-11-run-slow-script-in-parallel-batches) switch for [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Is it the other way around?... I didn't know. I knew the opposite. Gee... So what should I do to speed it up?... It's a simple task. It's a repetitive task, so the computer doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: There are 16,000 lines. document.. ip address I want to enter documents quickly. But it's not easy. It's too difficult to block China, Russia, and North Korea on a country-by-country basis.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/oklokl/advfirewall-ip-list-firehol_level1.netset/blob/main/out.txt) This is the document. It should be entered as `csv` so there were no errors. You will enter this. The quantity is too much.

Comment: And the slow and old windows security system.. very difficult because i am a beginner.

Comment: 45% cpu usage is actually quite high in my opinion so just let it run is all i can say at this stage! you dont seem to have PowerShell 7 so i dont think you can get much better than what you already have

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I'll install it now. I hope it works.

Comment: I installed it. Gee, the result is... it works slower for me. I'm sorry. haha..

Comment: yes because now that you have powershell 7 you can use the parallel feature! let me create an answer for you quick

Answer (score 2):

To speed up loops in PowerShell 7. Use the `Foreach-Object -parallel` functionality.

So change your script to the below:

1.ps1

```
Start-Process Pwsh.exe -Argumentlist "-file test1.ps1"
Start-Process Pwsh.exe -Argumentlist "-file test2.ps1"
```

test1.ps1

```
get-content "out_1.csv" | Foreach-Object -parallel {
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'A HTTP-Inbound' -Profile any -Direction Inbound -Action Block -RemoteAddress $_ | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Bad news... I failed. I think... Two guesses. There seems to be a traffic proposal. Although it works normally at first. Eventually, it became very slow.

Comment: Since `windows defender` is a security service, it seems to have control over external systems. That's my guess. I think this is the limit.

Comment: Please let me know if registration is a quick success. thank you. I have failed. 16000 ip address.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that's good news. There's something made by an expert. It's working fine. I'm going to write this. I just can't do it.

Comment: [link](https://www.sans.org/blog/windows-firewall-script-to-block-ip-addresses-and-country-network-ranges/) I found it. Someone told me before.. The file did not work because it was an old file. But this works fine.

Comment: However, I think the information you provided will be helpful to students. thank you.